# Complexity class of an algorithm

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, time-complexity

What is the complexity class of an algorithm that runs in $n^{\mathcal{O}(\sqrt{n}log(n))}$ time?

As $n$ gets large $\sqrt{n}log(n)$ increases at a very slow rate. Does this mean that the algorithm has the same complexity as $n^{\mathcal{O}(1)}$, which would be in $P$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, $\sqrt{n}$ increases far faster than $O(1)$, and $n^{\sqrt{n}}$ grows far faster than $n^{O(1)}$.  No, it certainly does not have the same runtime.  See [Sorting functions by asymptotic growth](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/824/755).

There may be no predefined complexity class; the complexity class is the class of all algorithms who run in time $n^{O(\sqrt{n} \log n)}$, and there's probably not much more to say.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Just to be clear, your saying it's inconclusive whether this is in $P$ or Sharp-$P$, right?

Comment: @Teferi, I was saying nothing about that - you didn't ask.  It's certainly not in P.